Geopandas error while writing to feather or parquet file format - UnsupportedGEOSVersionError: The "iso" option requires at least GEOS 3.10.0
When trying to write the pandas geodataframe "gdf" to a feather file format, I receive the error message UnsupportedGEOSVersionError: The "iso" option requires at least GEOS 3.10.0
gdf.to_feather("California_Buildings.feather")

My current version of GEOS in my environment is 3.12.1 which should satisfy this requirement... though I do not import GEOS directly in my code because write_feather is a geopandas function. Is there something I am missing?
*Edited to add - output from geopandas.show_versions():
SYSTEM INFO
-----------
python     : 3.11.7 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:05:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable : C:\Users\AWertheim\anaconda3\python.exe
machine    : Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0

GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO
---------------------
GEOS       : 3.8.0
GEOS lib   : None
GDAL       : 3.6.2
GDAL data dir: None
PROJ       : 9.3.1
PROJ data dir: C:\Users\AWertheim\anaconda3\Library\share\proj

PYTHON DEPENDENCIES
-------------------
geopandas  : 0.14.2
numpy      : 1.26.4
pandas     : 2.1.4
pyproj     : 3.6.1
shapely    : 2.0.1
fiona      : 1.9.5
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : None
matplotlib : 3.8.0
mapclassify: 2.5.0
pygeos     : None
pyogrio    : None
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : 14.0.2
rtree      : 1.0.1

Full error message here:
UnsupportedGEOSVersionError               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_52736\3260101815.py in <cell line: 0>()
      1 #Feather
      2 start = time.time()
----> 3 test_file.to_feather("California_Buildings.feather")
      4 #og_file.to_feather("California_Buildings.feather")
      5 #pyarrow.feather.write_feather(og_file, "California_Buildings.feather")

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_feather(self, path, index, compression, schema_version, **kwargs)
   1161         from geopandas.io.arrow import _to_feather
   1162 
-> 1163         _to_feather(
   1164             self,
   1165             path,

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\arrow.py in _to_feather(df, path, index, compression, schema_version, **kwargs)
    392 
    393     path = _expand_user(path)
--> 394     table = _geopandas_to_arrow(df, index=index, schema_version=schema_version)
    395     feather.write_feather(table, path, compression=compression, **kwargs)
    396 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\arrow.py in _geopandas_to_arrow(df, index, schema_version)
    274                 )
    275                 break
--> 276     df = df.to_wkb(**kwargs)
    277 
    278     table = Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=index)

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_wkb(self, hex, **kwargs)
   1012         # Encode all geometry columns to WKB
   1013         for col in df.columns[df.dtypes == "geometry"]:
-> 1014             df[col] = to_wkb(df[col].values, hex=hex, **kwargs)
   1015 
   1016         return df

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py in to_wkb(geoms, hex, **kwargs)
    192     if not isinstance(geoms, GeometryArray):
    193         raise ValueError("'geoms' must be a GeometryArray")
--> 194     return vectorized.to_wkb(geoms._data, hex=hex, **kwargs)
    195 
    196 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\geopandas\_vectorized.py in to_wkb(data, hex, **kwargs)
    193 def to_wkb(data, hex=False, **kwargs):
    194     if compat.USE_SHAPELY_20:
--> 195         return shapely.to_wkb(data, hex=hex, **kwargs)
    196     elif compat.USE_PYGEOS:
    197         return pygeos.to_wkb(data, hex=hex, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\Lib\site-packages\shapely\io.py in to_wkb(geometry, hex, output_dimension, byte_order, include_srid, flavor, **kwargs)
    185         raise TypeError("flavor only accepts scalar values")
    186     if lib.geos_version < (3, 10, 0) and flavor == "iso":
--> 187         raise UnsupportedGEOSVersionError(
    188             'The "iso" option requires at least GEOS 3.10.0'
    189         )

UnsupportedGEOSVersionError: The "iso" option requires at least GEOS 3.10.0
'''


I tried geopandas.write_feather(), as well as pyarrow.feather.write_feather(). Both resulted in error messages.


Can you add geopandas.show_versions() to the notebook you are getting this error in and add the output to your question?

@Pieter just edited to add - looks like geopandas is running GEOS 3.8.0

I think your conda environment is somehow not activated properly, leading to geopandas finding the binaries (gdal, geos,...) wherever it finds them instead of the ones in the environment you want. I rarely use notebooks, so I'm afraid I don't know how to fix this...

For me it was an issue with WKB vs WKT, though I was writing to a parquet file not to feather format. I resolved this by encoding the geometry column to WKT before writing out to file.
gdf = gdf.to_wkt()


One way is to update geos in your conda (not OS) environment to 3.10:
conda install geos=3.10 -c conda-forge
Note: This causes several packages to be downgraded, so YMMV
Another possibility is to update shapely which might be referencing an older version of GEOS (see https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#dependencies)

I got this when running an interpreter with geopandas, pysparkm, pyarrow, and pyogrio. It seems like one of these might be enforcing a shapely version, so I tried:
pip install shapely --upgrade

and now I can save to parquet.
